# Jasper reports: When accessing a database record field in jrxml it gives value in different line

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation, text-alignment

I am using jasper reports to generate a pdf, the attribute **billingAddressCustomerName** in below code gives first name and last name. But if the first name and last name are of single character, then it is returned in different lines:

What I am getting:

```
A
B
```

(A and B in different line)

What I should get :

```
A B
```

Code:

```
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="26" y="101" width="230" height="83">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement markup="styled">
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2" lineSpacingSize="1.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{billingAddressCustomerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe those are two separate rows? Seems strange since full names work.

Comment: Yeah watch out maybe you have a \n in data.

Comment: I'm wondering if some width calculations are going wonky when the text being evaluated is very short/narrow. Along that line of thought, I should point out that your property name value of "local_mesure_unitwidth" looks like it might be misspelled: is that supposed to be "local_measure_unitwidth" instead?

Comment: @acg_so  I did this also but no luck.. Trying to resolve this.